# what's the best way to deal with inheritance in django

Tags: python, django, database, django-models, orm

i have three types of products Course,Book, Paint, and i have A Cart and CartItem models,i was thinking of using multitable inheritance in Django which will be something like this:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_lenght=50)
    ......
class Course(Product):
    ......
class Book(Product):
  ......
class Cart(models.Model):
  .....
class CartItem(models.Model):
   cart = models.ForeignKey(Cart)
   product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
```

but i was reading that multitable inheritance is not good to use due to it's impact on the performance, so what's the best approach to deal with this?

Comment: This is totally subjective to me but multi-table inheritance is not very maintainable in the long run. I always prefer using abstract models and it remains easily customizable, docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes

Comment: But i can't use abstract vmodels because then i am gonna have to create a CartItem table special for each type of a product if i make Product class as abstract @ybl

Comment: While reading your code I get a little idea of what your are trying to do. In your place I would probably not go with multiple classes for each product, it will become hard to follow  with lot of different products. Instead, I would go for only one class : **Product** with a **JSONField** inside, which will have all carac. for a product. You could define each JSON for each product in a directory.